# Read Json file containing umlaut in c#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am trying to Read Json file containing umlaut in c#, following is the format of the file:

```
{
    "BankCodeOertlich": "59000000",
    "BicOertlich": "",
    "ErgaenzungName": "Außenst. Sulzbach",
    "HauptstelleAussenstellen": "Außenstelle v. Finanzamt Saarbrücken Am"
}
```

I am using following code to read the json in c#:

```
public static List<T> Load<T>(string filePath)
{
    using (var stream = File.OpenRead(filePath))
    {
        var reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
        List<T> data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(reader.ReadToEnd());
        return data;
    }
}
```

I am getting the following output:

```
{
    "BankCodeOertlich": "59000000",
    "BicOertlich": "",
    "ErgaenzungName": "Au?enst. Sulzbach",
    "HauptstelleAussenstellen": "Au?enstelle v. Finanzamt Saarbr?cken Am"
}
```

This is just a example not a actual ouput. I tried to change to Encoding of StreamReader but its not working. is there any better way to do it?

Comment: Is your JSON file saved using unicode encoding?

Comment: Ensure the data is *really* Unicode. .NET uses Unicode internally and the  stream classes use UTF8 by default. Most likely, the data is ASCII and your system's locale can't handle all Latin characters

Comment: Are you sure the file is really encoded in UTF8? Try `Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1")` instead

Comment: i tried default and ASCII but it still showing same .. 
@kraden: i didn't specify encoding while saving the file

Comment: which means then as utf-8

Comment: Maybe reading works as expected, but something happens with the output? Just a wild guess...

Comment: @ammoQ: thanks man it is working ... i tried Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1")  and it is working

Comment: @AmanullahTariq that means you *didn't* read a UTF8 file. Either the file was converted to ASCII or you didn't use the code you specified to save it. Did you edit it in a text editor perhaps, that saved it as ASCII?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos ISO-8859-1(8bit) is a bit more than ASCII (7bit)

Comment: @AmanullahTariq Made my comment an answer you can upvote and/or accept ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The file is not encoded in UTF8, try Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1") instead.